# in C# forms ,notification window is populated even no code is written

Tags: c#, notifications, sqlcommand

I am writing a program to create a system tray to popup messages.
In the program I check if its a valid user and then a notification will be displayed

else

no notification message will be displayed.

But if the user(user code) has no meeting then blank notification message popup is coming.

I want to hide the notification message.

Please help me.

I have written code

```
using (SqlConnection CNN = new SqlConnection(AppManager.GetConnectionString()))
                    {
                        CNN.Open();
                        //getting all records from Meeting

                        using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
                        {


       using (DataTable dtMeeting = new DataTable())
                            {

                                scmd.CommandText = "SELECT MeetingNumber from Meeting";

                                scmd.Connection = CNN;
                                SqlDataAdapter sdaMeeting = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
                                sdaMeeting.Fill(dtMeeting);


                                foreach (DataRow drMeeting in dtMeeting.Rows)
                                {

                                    using (DataTable dtAttendies = new DataTable())
                                    {
                                        scmd.CommandText = "SELECT MEETING.MeetingNumber, MEETING.MeetingType," +
                                          " MEETINGTYPEMASTER.MeetingTypeName, MEETING.MeetingName,MEETING.Location," +
                                          " MEETING.StartTime, MEETING.EndTime, MEETINGATTENDEES.AttendeeType," +

                                          " MEETING.Prepared, MEETING.PreparedBy, MEETING.PreparedDateTime," +
                                          " MEETING.BranchCode" +
                                          " FROM MEETING, MEETINGTYPEMASTER, EMPLOYEEMASTER ,MEETINGATTENDEES," +
                                          " DESIGNATIONMASTER, DEPARTMENTMASTER,USERMASTER" +
                                          " Where MEETING.MeetingType=MEETINGTYPEMASTER.MeetingTypeCode" +
                                          " And EMPLOYEEMASTER.EmployeeCode=MEETINGATTENDEES.EmployeeCode" +
                                          " And EMPLOYEEMASTER.DepartmentCode=DEPARTMENTMASTER.DepartmentCode" +
                                          " And EMPLOYEEMASTER.DesignationCode=DESIGNATIONMASTER.DesignationCode" +
                                          " And MEETING.BranchCode=xxx" +
                                          " And MEETING.MeetingNumber=MEETINGATTENDEES.MeetingNumber" +
                                          " And MEETING.MeetingNumber= " + drMeeting["MeetingNumber"] + "" + //This meeting number coming from outer loop
                                          " And EMPLOYEEMASTER.EmployeeCode=USERMASTER.EmployeeCode" +
                                          " And USERMASTER.UserCode=2";//User code

                                        scmd.Connection = CNN;
                                        SqlDataAdapter sdaAttendies = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
                                        sdaAttendies.Fill(dtAttendies);
                                        if (dtAttendies.Rows.Count != 0)
                                        {                                          
                                            foreach (DataRow drAttendies in dtAttendies.Rows)
                                            {
                                                lblMeetingType.Text = dtAttendies.Rows[0]["MeetingTypeName"].ToString();
                                                lblMeetingName.Text = dtAttendies.Rows[0]["MeetingName"].ToString();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {     // if the user code has no meeting still the blank popup is coming                                     
                                           //Here no code is given  but still the notification popup is coming

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    this.Close();
                }                

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            }      
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                ShowInTaskbar = false;
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
            }
        }
 private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;            
        }    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          

        }                              
 static class Program
    {
              [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {            
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
          }
```

I am unable to find the error.
Please don't help me to display notification message.

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: I don't see any code where a notification is displayed. Please add the relevant code.

Comment: if (dtAttendies.Rows.Count != 0) 
it should be 
if (dtAttendies.Rows.Count > 0)

Comment: I think you need to maintain flag to identify when to show notification when to not.

Comment: You are showing the balloon when the form is minimized, you aren't taking in account if there are or not meetings.